# Defining where usercontrol output will be

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and user controls. I am trying to generate a javascript array from my C# code.

On the main .aspx page I have this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="main.aspx.cs" Inherits="main" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/table.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="myTable" %>
```

Then on my table.asc.cs I have this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (...)
    this.LoadDataFromDB();
    (...)
}

private void LoadDataFromDB()
{
    (...)
    Response.Write(array);
    (...)
}
```

My *problem* is that the array is being written before the `<html>` tags. It still works fine, but, how could I put it inside the `<head>` tags for instance?

Thank you

UPDATE:

I added this to my main.aspx

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literalarray" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough"  Text="" />
```

and this to my ascx.cs:

```
   Literal Literalarray= new Literal();
   Literalarray.Text = output;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code in the ascx.cs:

```
   Literal Literalarray= new Literal();
   Literalarray.Text = output;
```

should be:

```
   Literalarray.Text = output;
```

Which should be in the Page_Load as a designer file will declare the literal type and allocate the space for it.  By declaring a new one, the old one may be hidden.  Also, be aware that if you are generating a JavaScript array that you also generate the script tags as part of the output as a literal doesn't do much decorating around the result.

---

I'd probably suggest putting a literal in the head on the main.aspx and load the data in there that way for one idea.

You could also do dynamic controls so that in the table.ascx.cs you create a Literal like you did previously and then add that to the head of the page assuming the head tag has a "runat=server" attribute so the code behind can use it.  I'm pretty sure that in the code behind for the table you could do something like this:

```
   Literal Literalarray= new Literal();
   Literalarray.Text = output;
   this.Page.head.AddControl(Literalarray);
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way I can get it working in my main.aspx ? Since the table.ascx loads up after the < /head>

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Literal` control instead of `Response.Write`. Place it on your control somewhere and set its `Text` property.

You have to place it on your control, not on your page and you don't need to reinitalize it.